# switching classes on elements with a carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with a "homemade" carousel, I can't use one standard as that provided by Bootstrap.

Here is approximately my code structure:

Images

```
 <img src="1.img"/>
 <img src="2.img"/>
 <img src="3.img"/>
```

Prev / Next buttons

```
 <div class="left"></div> left button
 <div class="right"></div> right button
```

These buttons make me go back and forth through the elements of the "ol".

Ol Table

```
 <ol>
      <li>Circle 1</li>
      <li class="active">Circle 2</li>
      <li>Circle 3</li>
 </ol>
```

If I click on a button, the corresponding data will be loaded and the button on which I click will have an "active" class.

The same has to be made with the Prev / Next buttons, and that's the problem.

Given an HTML "ol" with three elements, I have to iterate so that, if I am in the second li element, if I click on Next it will go forth on the third li element, and if I click Back it will go back to the first

I assume to start with the second element and class active.

I can use the jQuery prev() and next() functions, but I have to make a for cycle because when I'm in the last li element, if I click the "next" button, the first li element has to be selected, and vice versa if I'm in the first, the last has to be "selected".

The result actually is something like this.

Onclick on "next" (and vice versa with "prev")

```
 $("li.active").next().addClass("active");
 $("li.active").prev().removeClass("active");
```

Two problems:
1) When I'm in the first element and I click to go to the second, the "active" class is given to the third li element and not to the second, but if I start from the last element, this works properly
2) If I'm in the first element, if I go back, it doesn't select the last element and vice versa

I think I need a for cycle to do this. Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code for next button:

```
$(".next").on("click", function(){
  moveToNext();
});//.next click

function moveToNext()
{
  var curIndex = $("ol li.active").index();
  var totalSlides = $("ol li").length;
  var nextIndex = curIndex + 1;

  if( nextIndex >= totalSlides )
  {
    nextIndex = 0;
  }//if

  $("ol li.active").removeClass("active");
  $("ol li").eq( nextIndex ).addClass("active").trigger("click");

}//moveToNext();
```

You can implement similarly for previous button.

Comment: Thanks, solved! Used the .first() and last() methods

Answer (score 0):

Pure JavaScript Solution. With next & previous.

```js
var next = document.querySelector('#next');
var previous = document.querySelector('#previous');
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.slider img');
var ols = document.querySelectorAll('.slider ol li');
var count = 0;

if (next) {
  next.addEventListener('click', nextImage, false);
  previous.addEventListener('click', prevImage, false);
}

for (var i = 0; i < ols.length; i++) {
  var element = ols[i];
  element.addEventListener('click', function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      if (images[i].classList.contains('active')) {
        images[i].classList.remove('active');
      }
      if (ols[i].classList.contains('active')) {
        ols[i].classList.remove('active');
      }
    }

    images[this.dataset.count].classList.add('active');
    ols[this.dataset.count].classList.add('active');
    count = this.dataset.count;
  });
}

function nextImage() {
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    if (images[i].classList.contains('active')) {
      images[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
    if (ols[i].classList.contains('active')) {
      ols[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
  }
  if (count === images.length - 1) {
    count = 0;
    images[count].classList.add('active');
    ols[count].classList.add('active');
  } else {
    count++;
    images[count].classList.add('active');
    ols[count].classList.add('active');
  }

}

function prevImage() {
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    if (images[i].classList.contains('active')) {
      images[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
    if (ols[i].classList.contains('active')) {
      ols[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
  }
  if (count === 0) {
    count = images.length - 1;
    images[count].classList.add('active');
    ols[count].classList.add('active');
  } else {
    count--;
    images[count].classList.add('active');
    ols[count].classList.add('active');
  }

}
```

```css
img {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
img.active {
  background: #DDD;
}
li.active {
  color: #000;
  background: #ddd;
}
ol li {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">

  <img class='active' src="" />
  <img src="" />
  <img src="" />

  <ol>
    <li data-count='0' class="active">Circle 1</li>
    <li data-count='1'>Circle 2</li>
    <li data-count='2'>Circle 3</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<button id="previous">Previous</button>

<button id="next">Next</button>
```